# Firefox - add certificate with certutil.exe - Windows XP

Tags: windows, firefox, certificate, certutil

I'm trying to import a certificate via cmd with certutil.exe

After I tried this command:

```
certutil.exe -A -n C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxx\Desktop\RootCert-somecert.cer -t c
```

It returns me

```
certutil.exe: function failed: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

1. make sure that the key3.db, cert8.db and secmod.db is in the same directory and in the current directory where you run the certutil. If you want to point another directory for the db, use -d argument.
2. -n argument is used to give alias to the certificate. To point the certificate to add, use the -i argument.

example:

```
certutil.ex -A -n "mycert" -i "C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxx\Desktop\RootCert-somecert.cer" -t c -d "C:\certdb"
```

hope it helps